# initialize '--Select--' in a dropdown list

Tags: html, angularjs

How can i initialize --select-- as the first option while I am fetching the select options from server using ng-options.. I have tried ng-init but it didn't workout..

> html element

```
<select   ng-options="item as item.approver1_name for item in request.approver1_data track by item.id" id="selectform" ng-model="selected_approver1_email"  >
```

I am able to fetch the list of approvers. But i need to add the --select-- option as default..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-options="region.code as region.name for region in regions" ng-model="region">
    <option style="display:none" value="">--select--</option>
    </select>
    <br>selected: {{region}}
</div>
```

Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.regions = [
        {
        name: "Alabama",
        code: "AL"},
    {
        name: "Alaska",
        code: "AK"},
    {
        name: "American Samoa",
        code: "AS"},
        ];
}
```

Here is the link to working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e0pkmoh1/) in which you can experiment further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init to set the default value, just append the default object to the array

```
$scope.approver1_data.push({
        id: '-1',
        name: '--Select--'
    });
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.approver1_data  = [ {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Option A'
    }, {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Option B'
    }, {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Option C'
    }];
    $scope.approver1_data.push({
        id: '-1',
        name: '--Select--'
    });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <form name="myForm">
            <label for="repeatSelect">Angular select:</label>
<select name="repeatSelect" 
   id="repeatSelect" 
   ng-model="repeatSelect"
   ng-init=" repeatSelect = '-1'"  
   ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in approver1_data">          
</select>
        </form>
        <br/> <tt>Selected value: {{repeatSelect}}</tt>

    </div>
</div>
<br/>
```